# How can i download a zip with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, download, zip, fs

i need to download files for my project. This is my current code:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const https = require("https")
const url = "https://f52.workupload.com/download/YYHAXY6t9VK"
https.get(url,(res) => {
  // Image will be stored at this path
  const path = `${__dirname}/clayent.zip`; 
  const filePath = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  res.pipe(filePath);
  filePath.on('finish',() => {
    filePath.close();
    console.log('Download Completed'); 
  })
})
```

It works with pngs, but not with zip-files. Is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)... Give us dependent packages and imports.

Comment: I updated it already

Comment: What do you mean by `but not with zip-files`? Any error returned or what?